# Live Loop Setup with Keyboard, Guitar and Mic with Boss RC-300

Tags: live, stage-setup, looping

I'm in the process of setting up a live looping setup, I want to use my vocals, guitar, midi/controller keyboard (controller sounds triggered with a DAW such as FL Studio or Logic). I was hoping anyone could give me some pointers or guidance with the setup at all, I'm currently thinking this is the best way to approach it:

**Keyboard** -> Laptop/PC (DAW) -> Boss RC-300 Loop Pedal (via 3.5mm Aux)

With:

**Guitar** -> FX Pedals (Delay and Reverb mainly) -> Boss RC-300 Loop Pedal (via 1/4" jack)

And:

**Mic** -> FX Pedals (TC-Helicon VoiceLive Play) -> Boss RC-300 Loop Pedal (via XLR)

Then output the Boss RC-300 to a PA/Speakers/Headphones, or if I want to record it, send it through a digital recorder or another Laptop/PC.

As far as I can see that should all work as I expect. So then on the Boss RC 300, I'll be able to have piano/strings loop and layered/dubbed on the 1st channel/pedal, my guitar on the 2nd channel and vocals on the 3rd channel for example!

So yeh, my question, can anyone see any flaws in this, or have any improvements that they could throw my way, if I'm missing anything or if you'd do anything differently in this setup?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

You may have issues running the Keyboard off the 3.5mm Aux in terms of volume and trim and possibly noise.

What I generally do is if I have more than two channels, I run all the signals through a mini-mixer  (like the Behringer 4 channel Euroracks) and then into one input on the RC-300.

It depends on the instrument mix, but I generally set my channels like this:

- First channel is a two-bar loop I use for percussion.
- Second channel is a 32-bar loop I use for laying down chords
- Third channel is another 32-bar loop for laying down melodies.
- Use the undo redo pedal as a "fourth channel" where I can switch back and forth between two parts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a guitar amp in that chain. Are you sure you'll like the direct sound of guitar -> pedals -> PA? I'd probably want at least a preamp if not a speaker sim as well. Maybe an amp sim in pedal form like a Sansamp?